# kml not displaying properly in embedded google maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-embed

I created a [kml layer](http://weather.hawaii.edu/vmap/hysplit/HYSPLIT_ps.kml) from some model output.  This data displays great on google earth with multiple overlaid polygons clearly visible.  I have attempted to display this data on the web with an embedded [google-maps](http://weather.hawaii.edu/vmap/hysplit/gmaps.cgi) but for some reason the bottom polygons are obscuring the upper ones.  I don't know how to go about correcting this other than rewriting the whole thing in a different programming language.  Right now the whole thing is written up in a simple CGI script. Is there a quick fix or easy solution to this issue to prevent me learning another programming language?

Comment: What is the problem?  You want the polygons under the bigger polygon to be on top?  You want to decrease the opacity?

Comment: It seems to be [rendered correctly](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?lat=19.333441&lng=-155.247162&zoom=10&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/hysplit_ps.kml) by the [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) third party KML parser (I think). Did the behavior change?  Seems like it might be an issue with the Google Maps KML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no "correct order", it depends on the parser in which order the Polygons will be rendered(the altitude will be ignored in a KMLLayer).

I didn't find any information about the ordering in the parser used for a KMLLayer, but as it seems the order is reversed related to the position in the document(at least I get the desired result for your KML-file with a reversed order of the polygons).

```js
      
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
   
        new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          driveFileId: "0BwPgjOA-i5WyRVBFU0QyUTM3b00",
          map:new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"))
        });
      });
```

```css
      html ,
      body ,
      #map-canvas { 
        height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This code seems to solve the issue I was having, however, I am not familiar with javascript so I am having a problem implementing this solution within my perl cgi script.  I imagine I need to add some print statements to the first few lines.